# How to align with the top (start) and bottom (end) of a dynamic Container?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am attempting to layout my container in a way that the Row is split twice, with two separate Columns.
Within those separate Columns, I would like to be able to display text at the bottom the Container as well as the top of the `Container` within the first Row that is expanded with the `flex: 7`. These text widgets will be dynamically changing upon drawing of each container within the first Column.

Changing `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start` to `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end` in the first `Row` within the `Container` gets my text where I want it to to be for the bottom portion of the text. But `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start` is working for the top portion of the text.

I have also attempted to use an `Expanded` widget between the two text fields, but this fails due to infinite height and it not being able to calculate the size of the Container. I do not want to add constraints to my container, unless the constraints are dynamically defined. I've also tried wrapping everything in `Expanded` widgets, I've attempted to use `Position` widgets, none of these options have worked.

Here is a really fancy drawing of what I am trying to accomplish:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
class TestingSomething extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: [
        Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 7,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          child: Text("Hope"),
                        ),
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                          child: Text("test"),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 3,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum")
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                      spreadRadius: 2,
                      blurRadius: 1,
                      offset: Offset(-1, 3), // changes position of shadow
                    ),
                  ],
                  color: Colors.red.shade600,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
            )
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I've been stuck on this for hours. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @pskink No luck there, tried every single option on each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works. Need to combine an `IntrinsicHeight` widget and a `Row` with `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch`

```
ListView(
    children: [
      Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: IntrinsicHeight(
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 7,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          child: Text("Hope"),
                        ),
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                          child: Text("test"),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 3,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum")
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                    spreadRadius: 2,
                    blurRadius: 1,
                    offset: Offset(-1, 3), // changes position of shadow
                  ),
                ],
                color: Colors.red.shade600,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
          )
        ],
      )
    ],
  )
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll look more into `IntrinsicHeight` to see why this works. But this is perfect!